# ERROR: ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I'm trying to run the app then it shows an error. Can anyone please check it.

```html
$ ionic serve
> ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ng] operable program or batch file.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Regards

Golam Rabbi